# Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET 6 & Angular 13 not producing wwwroot files

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp-net-core-spa-services

When I add files to the wwwroot folder, they are not available in the Angular app.

For example, create a new `ASP.NET Core with Angular` project, and run it. The `favicon.ico` in wwwroot will not show in the browser. Similarly, if I put an image file in the `wwwroot` folder, it will not load in the angular app.

However, I can put the image in the `ClientApp/src/assets` folder, and then access it on `assets/img.jpg`.

I tried things like `builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles();` to no avail. However, as the favicon should really work out the box, I would assume it's an issue that shouldn't require further configuration?

Comment: What is the directory relationship to where the Angular App compiled into its .js and .css files relative to the wwwroot? I've always found it easier to keep the front-end assets in the angular asset folder, and only use the path to wherever wwwroot ends up being relative to Angular for assets that I cannot store in the Angular project for whatever reason.

Comment: Also could be of interest to add the wwwroot path to the "assets" array in your angular.json and see how that affects your results.

Comment: I don’t think you can add iit to angular.json as it can’t be a level up from the angular app root folder.

Comment: It seems for some reason the wwwroot folder is not being copied when it builds. I thought that’s what usestaticfiles should do, though. @cklimowski

Comment: @Sean, any positive news regarding this?

Comment: @SarathMohandas I've been using the `assets` folder alternative - I gave up trying to ge tthe `wwwroot` folder to work.

Comment: @Sean, there is a solution by changing the  updating the url values to proxy.config.js